# Undefined function wptexturize()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, undefined

I'm really new to wordpress and I had just encountered this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wptexturize() in /var/www/wp-admin/menu-header.php:141
```

I also tried checking on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/ and I had traced the callers and functions used by this wptexturize() to no avail.

The main issue seems to be that the function is undefined.
So I checked on the formatting.php file and there it was, clearly defined.

My guess is that the function is being called before it was even initialized. But please correct me if I am wrong.

If someone had encountered this issue before, I would really love to have some of your guidance on resolving this issue.

Thank you

Comment: try to install another instance of wordpress in your local to check, but probably an installation issue, you could try to reinstall wp

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the suggestion.
I'll try it out on another instance.
Do you also happen to know what might have caused this?

Comment: I'm not sure why, I maintain more than 10 wordpress sites and v5.5.1 (latest) works fine. core has been working fine since

Comment: Ok, I'm currently doing what you suggested, will be posting an update later once it is complete.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the very long update.

We were able to finally resolve this.
The site was under a malware attack and it was disrupting all the critical files for our site to properly function.

so a malware cleanup resolved the issue.

Thanks to GoDaddy Support for pointing this out and helping to resolve it

Answer (score 3):

I started getting the same error too. I think it's because of a plugin but I'm not sure which one.

To correct it, download wordpress (latest.zip), unzip it in your website root directory.
Then refresh your wordpress installation by overwriting the wp-admin and wp-includes directories.

```
cd /var/www/yoursite
wget https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
unzip latest.zip

cp -R wordpress/wp-admin .  
cp -R wordpress/wp-includes .

chown -R www-data:www-data wp-admin; 
chown -R www-data:www-data wp-includes;
```

Then you will get rid of the error.

Comment: Thanks for this,
I am currently doing this exact thing.
Will update you later for the results.

Comment: Hi, the issue is still there,
I had downloaded the latest version and extracted them to the root directory.
However I now see an Internal Server Error on my console.

I'm currently reverting back.

Comment: This is what I have now:
"There has been a critical error on your website."
and
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

I'm still searching in the internet for any possible reasons and solutions for this.
But I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Please add define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );    to your   wp-config.php   and reload your site.. You should see details for the errors.

Comment: Update:
I was able to restore my site using your recommendation and thank you for it!

However, just 24 hours after the restore, I am back to the original problem that I have.
still with the wptexturize

Comment: @JeroDungog  The same here. I can advise you to check crontab and disable automated jobs related with your plugins.  Also uninstalll all unnecessary plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Arda Tunccekic would fix your problem, but not for a long time!
Most probably your site is infected by some MalWare, in order to confirm, try to install special MalWare and security plugins like WebDefender for example, and scan your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using fresh wp-includes solved the undefined fatal error. But the main issue is that it is related with malware infection. There was latest issue with Vulneribility with pluging wp-file-manager. I am also looking into if that's the main reason.

https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-file-manager/reviews/

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to fix this issue by overwriting the the directories

wordpress/wp-admin
wordpress/wp-includes

After that, the website was okay again, but one day after the problem was back again.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce it by restarting apache2.

`systemctl restart apache2`

Still I cannot find a way to resolve it. I may try later when the website usage is low. I will come and update later once I can find a solution for it.